# Correct birthday date format in England

Tags: time, dates

What is the correct date formate in England?
If I want to write someone's birthday date what is the correct way to do it?
"Born May 5, 2000 at 05:00", or "Born 5th May, 2000 at 05:00", or "Born fifth May, 2000 at 05:00", or none of this is correct?

Comment: There is no CORRECT format. In my experience, most UK government agencies will ask for your birthday in a dd/mm/yyyy format, unlike American agencies which appear to prefer a mm/dd/yyyy format. I am not aware of any format that includes the time of birth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the short format, 2nd May is always written with the day number first in the UK (2/5/1990), never with the month first (5/2/1990). (Year-first may be used in specific scenarios, for example by IT professionals.)

For the long format (i.e. with the month written as a word), day-first and month-first are both in use. Some consider month-first an Americanism in the long format too, although it's not clear this is really the case. Formal usage tends to prefer day-first, though - but unlike in the US, day-first is found informally as well.

When day-first format is used, British usage prefers to avoid a comma between the month and the year. It also usually avoids a comma between the day of the week (where specified) and the date number.

"5th May 1990" and "5 May 1990" are considered equally correct.

If using the 24-hour clock, it's probably preferable to refer to 05:00 with a leading zero before the 5. In 12-hour format, the leading zero is best avoided.

It isn't typical to specify someone's time of birth at all, although of course you can if you wish.